# How can I retrieve the hyperlink from a cell in a Google spreadsheet using .NET API?

Tags: .net, hyperlink, formula, google-sheets-api

I am using [Google Spreadsheet .NET API](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/spreadsheets/) and I have a column with cells which are hyperlinks. I want to retrieve the formula of the cell via C#. I refer to this question ["How can I retrieve the hyperlink from a data cell in google apps script?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13847007/how-can-i-retrieve-the-hyperlink-from-a-data-cell-in-google-apps-script) which is similar to mine. I am borrowing the [image: picture from the mentioned question] for a proper visualization of the problem.

I am using the following code from the google tutorials:

```
using System;
using Google.GData.Client;
using Google.GData.Spreadsheets;

namespace MySpreadsheetIntegration
{
  class Program
  {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      SpreadsheetsService service = new SpreadsheetsService("MySpreadsheetIntegration-v1");

      //AUTH

      SpreadsheetQuery query = new SpreadsheetQuery();

      SpreadsheetFeed feed = service.Query(query);

      SpreadsheetEntry spreadsheet = (SpreadsheetEntry)feed.Entries[0];
      Console.WriteLine(spreadsheet.Title.Text);

      WorksheetFeed wsFeed = spreadsheet.Worksheets;
      WorksheetEntry worksheet = (WorksheetEntry)wsFeed.Entries[0];

      CellQuery cellQuery = new CellQuery(worksheet.CellFeedLink);
      CellFeed cellFeed = service.Query(cellQuery);

      foreach (CellEntry cell in cellFeed.Entries)
      {
        Console.WriteLine(cell.InputValue);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

but `cell.InputValue` is always `null`. I am missing something, can u help?

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 1):

cell.InputValue would be used to *input* a *value* into the cell. It would be used as:

```
cell.InputValue = string;
```

Google Spreadsheets API is very limited in its capabilities. It's my understanding that, while it can read from and write to cells, any formula or formatting contained therein (including hyperlinks) is out of reach of the API.