# Apps Script: how to get hyperlink from a cell where there is no formula

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, hyperlink, cell, google-sheets-formula

I have a sheet where hyperlink is set in cell, but *not through formula*. When clicked on the cell, in "fx" bar it only shows the value.

I searched on web but everywhere, the info is to extract hyperlink by using `getFormula()`.

But in my case there is no formula set at all.

I can see hyperlink as you can see in image, but it's not there in "formula/fx" bar.

[image]

How to get hyperlink of that cell using Apps Script or any formula?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

When Excel file including the cells with the hyperlinks is converted to Google Spreadsheet, such situation can be also seen. In my case, I retrieve the URLs using Sheets API. A sample script is as follows. I think that there might be several solutions. So please think of this as one of them.

**When you use this script, please enable Sheets API at Advanced Google Services and API console. You can see about how to enable Sheets API at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48754286/retrieving-google-sheets-cell-border-style-programmatically/48756509#48756509).**

#### Sample script:

```
var spreadsheetId = "### spreadsheetId ###";
var res = Sheets.Spreadsheets.get(spreadsheetId, {ranges: "Sheet1!A1:A10", fields: "sheets/data/rowData/values/hyperlink"});
var sheets = res.sheets;
for (var i = 0; i < sheets.length; i++) {
  var data = sheets[i].data;
  for (var j = 0; j < data.length; j++) {
    var rowData = data[j].rowData;
    for (var k = 0; k < rowData.length; k++) {
      var values = rowData[k].values;
      for (var l = 0; l < values.length; l++) {
        Logger.log(values[l].hyperlink) // You can see the URL here.
      }
    }
  }
}
```

#### Note:

- Please set `spreadsheetId`.
- `Sheet1!A1:A10` is a sample. Please set the range for your situation.
- In this case, each element of `rowData` is corresponding to the index of row. Each element of `values` is corresponding to the index of column.

#### References:

- [Method: spreadsheets.get](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/get)

If this was not what you want, please tell me. I would like to modify it.

Comment: This is what I wanted. But it shouldn't be a part of Advance API. There should have been some method in Class Range of Spreadsheet to get this easily.
Anyway, Thanks!

Comment: @Irfan Alam Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. When I found the methods for this situation at Class SpreadsheetApp, I would like to add it.

Comment: @IrfanAlam check [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61921034/555121) inspired by Tanaike's another snippet that uses `SpreadsheetApp`

Answer (score 25):

When a cell has only one URL, you can retrieve the URL from the cell using the following simple script.

```
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1");
var url = sheet.getRange("A2").getRichTextValue().getLinkUrl(); //removed empty parentheses after getRange in line 2
```

Source: https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/d39b4b5ccc5a1d50f5b8b75febd807a6

Comment: For this to work the cell has to contain a string rather than a number. I've forced the number by adding a single quote at the front.

Answer (score 1):

**Hey all,**

**I hope this helps you save some dev time, as it was a rather slippery one to pin down...**

This custom function will take all hyperlinks in a Google Sheets cell, and return them as text formatted based on the second parameter as either [JSON|HTML|NAMES_ONLY|URLS_ONLY].

**Parameters:**

*cellRef* : You must provide an A1 style cell reference to a cell.
Hint: To do this within a cell without hard-coding
a string reference, you can use the CELL function.
eg: "=linksToTEXT(CELL("address",C3))"

*style*   : Defines the formatting of the output string.
Valid arguments are : [JSON|HTML|NAMES_ONLY|URLS_ONLY].

### Sample Script

```
/** 
 * Custom Google Sheet Function to convert rich-text 
 * links into Readable links.
 * Author: Isaac Dart ; 2022-01-25
 * 
 * Params
 *  cellRef : You must provide an A1 style cell reference to a cell. 
 *            Hint: To do this within a cell without hard-coding
 *            a string reference, you can use the CELL function. 
 *            eg: "=linksToTEXT(CELL("address",C3))"
 * 
 *  style   : Defines the formatting of the output string.
 *            Valid arguments are : [JSON|HTML|NAMES_ONLY|URLS_ONLY].
 * 
 */

function convertCellLinks(cellRef = "H2", style = "JSON") {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var cell = sheet.getRange(cellRef).getCell(1,1);
  var runs = cell.getRichTextValue().getRuns();
  var ret = "";
  var lf =  String.fromCharCode(10); 
  runs.map(r => {
      var _url = r.getLinkUrl();
      var _text = r.getText();
      if (_url !== null && _text !== null) {
        _url = _url.trim(); _text = _text.trim();
        if (_url.length > 0 && _text.length > 0) {
          switch(style.toUpperCase()) {
            case "HTML": ret += '<a href="' + _url + '">' + _text + '}</a>' + lf; break;
            case "TEXT": ret += _text + ' : "' + _url + '"' + lf; break;
            case "NAMES_ONLY" : ret += _text + lf; break;
            case "URLS_ONLY" : ret += _url + lf; break;
            //JSON default : ...
            default: ret +=  (ret.length>0?(','+ lf): '') +'{name : "' + _text + '", url : "' + _url + '"}' ; break; 
          }
          ret += lf;
        }
      }
  });
  if (style.toUpperCase() == "JSON") ret = '[' + ret + ']';
  //Logger.log(ret);
  return ret;
}
```

Cheers,

Isaac

Answer (score -1):

I tried solution 2:

```
var urls = sheet.getRange('A1:A10').getRichTextValues().map( r => r[0].getLinkUrl() ) ;
```

I got some links, but most of them yielded null.
I made a shorter version of solution 1, which yielded all the links.

```
  const id = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getId() ;
  let res = Sheets.Spreadsheets.get(id,
     {ranges: "Sheet1!A1:A10", fields: "sheets/data/rowData/values/hyperlink"});
  var urls = res.sheets[0].data[0].rowData.map(r => r.values[0].hyperlink) ;
```