# Exporting a Google Sheet with Links to TSV

Tags: google-sheets

I have a Google Sheet that has links where the link text does not match the URL. I want to export this to TSV (or CSV, doesn't matter) and still have access to both the link text and the URL.

When I use the normal TSV export, it includes the link text but not the URL.

Is there a way to get both the link text and the URL?

Comment: You want to retrieve both ``### link text ###`` and ``### URL ###`` from ``=HYPERLINK("### link text ###","### URL ###")`` put in a cell as a TSV file. If my understanding is correct, how about using script? ``=HYPERLINK()`` is a formula. Unfortunately, in the current stage, there are no methods for exporting directly the formulas as a TSV file. So it is required to prepare a script for exporting them. How about this? If this was not the direction you want, I apologize.

Comment: I'm fine with anything that works. In this case though I don't think the `=HYPERLINK()` function is used - when I click the cell the cell contents area at the top just shows the link text. I guess the cell contents are rich text?

Comment: Thank you for replying. Is your situation this? https://stackoverflow.com/q/53863752/7108653 Even if it's so, you can achieve it using a script. By the way, when you provide a sample Spreadsheet, it will help users understand your situation and think of your solution. How about this?