# Accessing a URL within a GSheet Cell which has been referenced by IMPORTRANGE and FILTER

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Source sheet contains a cell which looks like this -- =HYPERLINK("https://drive.google.com/drive/u/0/folders/somegdrivesheet","Completed")
I then have a complex formula which references that cell and then delivers it to another sheet.
At this point i can click on the output of the formula and still see its a URL - click the cell - link becomes available and i can navigate to it.

I cant workout how to extract the URL from this cell so i can use it in the referencing sheet programatically.

Tried various things:-

```
ISURL is false for the cell with the value
ISFORMULA is false for the cell with the value
So i cannot address the formula directly
```

Created custom function where i pass in the cell address and attempt to grab the values from the cell. All i can get is the text value associated with the cell and not the URL.

```
cellValue = cell.getValue(); -- Just text value not URL
cellValue = cell.getValues(); -- NOTHING
cellValue = JSON.stringify(cell); -- NOTHING
cellValue = cell.getRichTextValue(); -- NOTHING
```

Any guidance appreciated.

Example GSheet [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/19c2Q6hGygtLLxD8rZL0CEog-iST3DsyMhSoGukdVALo/edit#gid=1514974436)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Apps Script: How to get Hyperlink from a cell where there is no formula Hyperlink](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53863752/apps-script-how-to-get-hyperlink-from-a-cell-where-there-is-no-formula-hyperlin)

Comment: That is the solution - thanks!

Comment: You can accept the question as a  duplicate.