# Google Sheets - Difference in Hyper Link and Insert Link

Tags: google-sheets, hyperlink, google-sheets-formula

I have a Google Sheet that is connected to an external Node JS app. The app uses Google App Script to access data in the different cells. In my cells I have what I would assume are hyperlinks but they don't behave how hyperlinks do in Google Sheets that I've seen in other people's examples.

In a "Normal" Google sheet a hyperlink would be the following formula

`=HYPERLINK("https://stackoverflow.com/", "Stack Overflow")`

However when putting the data in the sheets I instead used the "Insert Link" option in Google Sheets

[image]

This results in my data being stored as just text in the formula bar, and on mouse hover I get a different kind of what I assume is still a hyperlink.

[image]

When I retrieve my data from the sheet I only seem to get the text and not the hyperlink. Could someone please clear up the difference between the Hyperlink formula and the Insert Link options?

Edit: Upon looking deeper into this I've come to the conclusion that these are still in fact hyperlinks the difference is that they for some reason do not put the links into the formula bar. Does anyone know how I can access these hyperlinks from The Google App Script API

Comment: Can this thread answer for your question? https://stackoverflow.com/q/53863752/7108653

Comment: Yes this solves my issue, thank you!

Comment: Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Apps Script: how to get hyperlink from a cell where there is no formula](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53863752/apps-script-how-to-get-hyperlink-from-a-cell-where-there-is-no-formula)