# Extract URL from copied text in Google Sheets

Tags: url, google-sheets, extract, paste

Hy.

I have a sheet with a text pasted from some external HTML site. It stands as the visual text, for example, "DUBLADO" is the cell and formula field.

It is not a `=HYPERLINK()` function (like `=HYPERLINK("www.google.com.br"; "Google")`). It is the text pasted with a URL embedded. In the formula field, is shows only the "DUBLADO".

How can I extract the URL from this kind of text?

Here is the sheet to see:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ldne4jXRXpBiUlF1PoXPOMXwIILbmhBZL5i19U-0deY/edit?usp=sharing

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In the current stage, this can be achieved by the script using Sheets API. You can see the sample script at [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53863752). In this case, the custom function cannot be used. So please be careful this.

Comment: @RafaGuillermo, very thanks for the answer. It worded great! As I just need to one cell, I simplified the function to one line and the result is:

var url = sheets[0].data[0].rowData[0].values[0].hyperlink;

:)