# Unable to get hyperlink from a Cell - Google Sheets

Tags: python-3.x, google-sheets, hyperlink, google-sheets-api

I working on Google Sheets and wanted to get sheet hyperlink from a cell via Google API. It shows the text only, but has hyperlink too.

[image]

As the selected Cell is a link and showing link also. But in the bar above, it is showing Text only. I'm using Google Sheets API v4 to get the Cell value but it is also returning only Cell Value (Rather I tried value_render_option='FORMULA' too).

what is wrong here.
Any type of help will be much appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Is this thread useful for your situation? https://stackoverflow.com/q/53863752/7108653

Comment: Yes, the case is as same as mine. But I want to scrape data using Python Script not the Google Apps Script.
Or Is there any way I can send Google Apps Script via Python authorizations where I'm using it?

Comment: Thank you for replying. In that case, how about using Sheets API with python?

Comment: I couldn't find a solution to do this with Google Sheets API Directly. My findings conclude that Google API lacks this functionality.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I deeply apologize my comments were not useful for your situation.

Comment: No Problem mate. It's kind gesture of yours.