# I'm trying to send an email from google spreadsheet, however the message is not copying the hyperlink

Tags: javascript, email, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have "to" in column A & "message/body" in column "B". I have a code which sends an email. However in my message I have a word hyperlinked to another sheet, while sending the email, the hyperlink is not considered. Please find the screenshot below.[image: The hyperlink is visible in column B]

However when the email is sent, the hyperlink is not visible. Please the image below

[image: The hyperlink is not considered in email]

```
    function sendEmails() {    
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var startRow = 2;
  var numRows = 1;
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, 2);
  var data = dataRange.getValues();
  for (var i in data) {
    var row = data[i];
    var emailAddress = row[0]; // First column
    var message = row[1]; // Second column
    var subject = 'Sending emails from a Spreadsheet';
    MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);
  }
}
```

Comment: Is this thread useful for your situation? https://stackoverflow.com/q/61787891/7108653

Comment: What does the actual value of the cell look like in message/body? Do you have embedded href in it?

Comment: Yes, I have embedded href in a cell..

Answer (score 2):

Use [Templated HTML](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/templates)

```
var htmlBody = HtmlService.createTemplate('Email with <a href=<?=link?>> Some link </a>');  

htmlBody.link = row[1];

MailApp.sendEmail({
  to: row[0],
  subject: 'Sending emails from a Spreadsheet',
  htmlBody: htmlBody.evaluate().getContent()
});
```

If you have embedded cell links, you can extract them using Advanced Sheets services, as describe [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53863752/apps-script-how-to-get-hyperlink-from-a-cell-where-there-is-no-formula), for example

```
var values = Sheets.Spreadsheets.get(SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getId(), {ranges: "Sheet1!B1:B10", fields: "sheets/data/rowData/values/hyperlink"})
var links = values.sheets[0].data[0].rowData.map(v => v.values[0].hyperlink);
```

them use them in templated HTML example I provided.

Comment: +1, You can even write the hyperlink in the cell like: Email with <a href=https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/mail/mail-app>Some link</a>

Comment: Thank you for the assistance.. However when the script is run, the body of the email looks like below

"Email with a *****link*****