# Extract Multiple Hyperlinks from a single Google sheet cell and append their respective URLs in the cell

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, hyperlink, google-sheets-api

I have a google sheet with each cell containing multiple Hyperlinks.

My goal is to:

1. extract url from say cell A1 (or the active cell/range)
2. **keep existing cell content** and append the extracted URL to the existing content (in the same cell)
3. Be able to do this for a range instead of each cell individually

Currently, I have this code that works for one cell with only one Hyperlink but gives an error

> TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined

when a cell contains multiple hyperlinks.

```js
function URL() {
  var spreadsheet =SpreadsheetApp.getActive(); 
  var sheet = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet();
  var id = spreadsheet.getId();
  var range = sheet.getActiveRange();
  var linkArray = Sheets.Spreadsheets.get(id, {ranges: sheet.getName() + "!" + 
  range.getA1Notation(), fields: "sheets/data/rowData/values/hyperlink"});
  var link = linkArray.sheets[0].data[0].rowData[0].values[0].hyperlink;
  var cellInE = sheet.getRange(range.getRow(), 5);
  var cellEcontent = sheet.getRange(range.getRow(), 5).getValues()
  var appnded = cellEcontent + String.fromCharCode(10) + link;
  cellInE.setValue(appnded);
}
```

I am new to google app scripts and coding in general. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Please add some sample data and clearly state if the "hyperlinks" are clickable or not. Also add the complete textual error message (the file name and line number are missing).

Answer (score 1):

You need to correctly iterate the linkArray, I found an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53863752/apps-script-how-to-get-hyperlink-from-a-cell-where-there-is-no-formula) and made a few brief modifications. It worked for me.

```
function myFunction() {
  var spreadsheetId = "1olBuawXzIxriAhWM2_e42LzjWM2fh_1aWitZkJMErWk";
  let rangeToSet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(spreadsheetId).getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var res = Sheets.Spreadsheets.get(spreadsheetId, { ranges: "Sheet1!A1:C3", fields: "sheets/data/rowData/values/hyperlink" });
  var sheets = res.sheets;
  for (var i = 0; i < sheets.length; i++) {
    var data = sheets[i].data;
    for (var j = 0; j < data.length; j++) {
      var rowData = data[j].rowData;
      for (var k = 0; k < rowData.length; k++) {
        var values = rowData[k].values;
        for (var l = 0; l < values.length; l++) {
          Logger.log(values[l].hyperlink) // You can see the URL here.
          // k is Row number
          //l is column number
          rangeToSet.getRange(k + 1, l + 1).setValue(values[l].hyperlink);
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Before:

[image]

Now:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for your response! when I run your code it says:
"Error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined"

Also, when I click debug and go through the variables, I cant seem to find "rowData" in there. I see "getRowData". I am looking in res/sheets[0]/data[0]....

Comment: Review the next: 1. in ranges: "Sheet1!A1:C3" review if it has the realy name Sheet and range. 2. enable advanced Sheets Api from "Services" options of Google apps script editor