# Extracting URL Links out of Google Sheets cell containing other text as well

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to write a function that takes a Google Sheet ID as an input and parses the spreadsheet, extracting URL links out of the cells when encountered. I wrote the following function based off of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39871890/how-to-get-url-from-google-spreadsheet-cell-with-google-apps-script) and [this blog post](https://yagisanatode.com/2017/12/13/google-apps-script-iterating-through-ranges-in-sheets-the-right-and-wrong-way/).

```
function getLinksFromSheet(sheetId){
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(sheetId); //general case
var sheets = ss.getSheets();

sheets.forEach(sheet => {
  var rangeData = sheet.getDataRange();
  var lastColumn = rangeData.getLastColumn();
  var lastRow = rangeData.getLastRow();
  var searchRange = sheet.getRange(1,1, lastRow, lastColumn);
  var rangeValues = searchRange.getRichTextValues();


  for (var i = 0; i < lastRow; i++){
    for (var j = 0 ; j < lastColumn; j++){
      Logger.log(rangeValues[i][j].getLinkUrl())
    }
  }
});
```

The function works well for extracting links from cells where the only text contents of the cell are the link (for example `http://google.com`). If, however, the cell contains other text that isn't a part of the link (for example `Link: http://google.com`), then the function returns `null`. Does anybody know of a way to modify my funtion so that it will still return the link from cells with other text besides a link in them?

Comment: Is the data in the cells structured in any specific way? Consider providing a copy of the spreadsheet showing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
  for (var i = 0; i < lastRow; i++){
    for (var j = 0 ; j < lastColumn; j++){
      const runs = rangeValues[i][j].getRuns();
      for (const v of runs) {
        Logger.log(v.getLinkUrl())
      }
    }
  }
```

Reference:

[getRuns()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/rich-text-value#getruns)