# Google Sheet API does not have getFormulaR1C1 fro CellEntry in PHP library

Tags: google-sheets-api

Is there a way to get Hyperlink or any formula from cell?

Basically, in worksheet I have a cell with hyperlink formula (=HYPERLINK('http://blabla.com', 'link1')). When I try to get value of this cell it gives me only visible content ('link1'). Is there any other way to have formula instead of visible content?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Aq4k.jpg)

Comment: What API call are you using?

Comment: here is my dependencies :   "asimlqt/php-google-spreadsheet-client": "2.*", "google/apiclient": "1.*"

Answer (score 0):

There's seems to be a way to do this using Apps Script (however you're using PHP so..)as mentioned in this [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13847007/how-can-i-retrieve-the-hyperlink-from-a-data-cell-in-google-apps-script):

```
function getURL() {
  var range = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getActiveCell();

  //logs - Google
  Logger.log(range.getValue());

  //logs - =HYPERLINK("http://www.google.com", "Google")
  Logger.log(range.getFormulaR1C1());

  //simple regex to get first quoted string
  var url = /"(.*?)"/.exec(range.getFormulaR1C1())[1];

  //logs - http://www.google.com
  Logger.log(url);
}
```

Comment: It should be supported fine in the Sheets V4 API. Just request valueRenderOption=FORMULA, then parse the result the same way you describe.

Comment: Alternately, you can use spreadsheets.get and take the values from the CellData, there's a "hyperlink" field and a "effective value" value.  One should have the URL and the other the display string.