# Unable to extract link text from tooltip in Google Spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm optimistic this question has already been answered. But if not, I'm hopeful that one of you JavaScript and Google Script experts can lend some assistance.

**Steps to Reproduce**

1. Go to www.nhl.com/stats/player
2. Copy the top few rows in the table (see screenshot #1)
3. Paste the contents into a new Google Spreadsheet
4. Click on the name of a player in the "Player" column (see screenshot #2)
5. Notice that the name itself is shown in the formula bar while the tooltip has a link to the player's profile on nhl.com

**What I Want to Happen**

I'd like to extract the link content that's shown in the toolip. (In screenshot #2 this is referring to the https://www.nh...layer/8471215 text.)

**What Actually Happens**

Nothing really. There's no way to see the tooltip content in the formula bar and, as far as I can tell, there's no function (e.g. hyperlink) to extract the tooltip content.

**Screenshots**

Screenshot #1

[image: Copy and paste default player text, note that the player's name is also a link]

Screenshot #2

[image: Tooltip contains link text that I'd like to extract]

**Other Notes**

I'm comfortable coding in JavaScript, but I have minimal experience in the script editor.

Comment: This is probably the closest you are going to get https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13847007/how-can-i-retrieve-the-hyperlink-from-a-data-cell-in-google-apps-script . In your case,  the solution won't work, because you are copying Rich Text Format

Comment: Thank you for the link, @AntonDementiev! It answered my question. (Apologies, I did search on SO before but I didn't see that question.) Unfortunately I think you're right. There doesn't appear to be any way to do what I'm trying.

Comment: The ugly hack workaround I did was to export the spreadsheet as an HTML file. Then I parsed it using PHP where I was able to extract the link using the freely available simple_html_dom.php library. I then exported the results as a CSV file and re-imported it into Google Sheets. This is acceptable given that I'm working on archived data, but it's about as inefficient as I can get... and I'm a seriously inefficient coder.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to what Anton has said, Apps Script has only support for A1 Notation and R1C1 formulas for now:

> - [getFormulas()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getformula)
>
> Returns the formula (A1 notation) for the top-left cell of the range,
>   or an empty string if the cell is empty or doesn't contain a formula.
>
> - [getFormulaR1C1()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getformular1c1)
>
> Returns the formula (R1C1 notation) for a given cell, or null if none.