# getRange().getFormula() with executed references

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Let's say that we have a cell with formula referring to another sheet, like
`=HYPERLINK("http://www.w3c.org";AnotherSheet!A1)`
Is there a simple way to getFormula() but with the reference already executed?

So the result of the function should be `=HYPERLINK("http://www.w3c.org";"W3C")` is `AnotherSheet!A1="W3C"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"a simple way" is subjective. The following is an example of how to do this by using an script:

```
function myFunction(reference) {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var formula = SpreadsheetApp
    .getActiveSpreadsheet()
    .getRange(reference)
    .getFormula();
  var text = /\((.*?),(.*?)\)/.exec(formula)[2];
  var value = sheet.getRange(text).getValue();
  return formula.replace(/\,.*?\)/,","+value+")");
}
```

Related

- [How can I retrieve the hyperlink from a data cell in google apps script?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13847007/1595451)

Answer (score -1):

Yes you just have to use the getValue() function instead of getFormula().

Stéphane

Comment: Thank you for the answer but not really. Then it returns the whole formula executed. So only `W3C` string in this case, not the `=HYPERLINK()` formula which I needed.

What I need is the 1st level of formula but all references done.

Comment: Ok I don't understand your question the first time. Second solution looks good.